# Ansible on Ubuntu 22.04 does not appear to be recognizing added repo

Tags: ansible, apt, ubuntu-22.04, nomad

I have a task taking the form below that is intended to install [Nomad](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/install) on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine. It throws on the "install nomad" play indicating it can't find the nomad package.

```
---
- name: add hashicorp signing key
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    url: https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg
    state: present

- name: add hashicorp repo
  apt_repository:
    repo: "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com {{ ansible_distribution_release }} main"
    state: present

- name: install nomad
  apt:
    name: ["nomad"]
    update_cache: yes
```

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Your playbook works for me when I target an Ubuntu 22.04 machine. Demo [here](https://asciinema.org/a/1rttjilb4hKLbY20mesTlfH8M).

Comment: @larsks Huh... weird. I think it may a problem with the VM I'm using. I'm trying to provision a Vagrant Qemu box: https://app.vagrantup.com/perk/boxes/ubuntu-2204-arm64 The only way I can get nomad to install at the moment is from the git repo itself. What Ubuntu22.04 release are you using?

Comment: Uhhhh...`/etc/os_release` says `VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"`.